# Google Cloud Django App Deployment - Permission Issues

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I'm following [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment?authuser=2#cloud-console) tutorial, yet I get stuck at the very end when I'm trying to deploy the app on the App Engine.
I get the following error message:

```
    Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/responder-289707/regions/europe-west6/operations/a0e5f3f4-29a7-49d8-98b5-4a52b7bf04ca error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-09-21T20:32:48.366Z12808.hy.0: Deployment Manager operation responder-289707/operation-1600720369987-5afd8c109adf5-6a4ad9a9-e71b9336 errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20200921t223056/resources/aef-default-20200921t223056"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/responder-289707/regions/europe-west6/autoscalers\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
```

I don't really understand why though. I'm have authenticated my gcloud, made sure my account has App Engine Admin/Deployment rights. Have everything in place.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently do not have the rights for autoscaling resources. This could be due to a free account or that you need different rights to deploy an autoscaling service (other than App Engine Admin/Deployment).

Seeing as how you're doing the tutorial you could define a static resource amount, this is safer for your wallet as wel.

`app.yaml`

```
# add this
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
```